# Civimail - loss of opt-out, unsubcribe & forwarding

Tags: civimail, urls, unsubscribe, opt-out

I have a Drupal 7.79 and a Joomla 3.9.25 site on the same server, both running Civi 5.35.1 and both with loss of unsubscribe, opt-out and forwarding capability.

Flexmailer is enabled on both sites.

In the CiviErrors extension output (which I don't understand) I see the lines below (note the occurence of &amp;).

[entryURL] => https://SITE-ONE/index.php?q=civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe&amp;reset=1&amp;jid=9099&amp;qid=1380011&amp;h=7d6e80ef654067bb

Full report at https://pastebin.com/vywyNWXH

[entryURL] => [https://www.SITE-TWO/index.php?option=com_civicrm\](https://www.SITE-TWO/index.php?option=com_civicrm%5C)&task=civicrm/mailing/optout&amp;h=9ee5ca3feec72a53&amp;jid=4304&amp;option=com_civicrm&amp;qid=557257&amp;reset=1

Full report at https://pastebin.com/ZhByJSB1

I have had problems with munged Civimail URL's before & wonder if this could be a similar issue.

The emails sent and received do not contain munged URL's and the 'access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages' permissions appear to be set correctly.

Comment: Can you edit the above civi version - I think you mean 5.35.1 not 3.35.1

Also - can you check if you have flexmailer enabled under extensions

Comment: Thanks. Flexmailer is enabled on both sites.